# How do I make a paragraph or div disappear with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use buttons to make paragraphs disappear with javascript, but when I make them "hidden", they still leave a big chunk of blank space. Is there a way I can remove that blank space?

The javascript:

```
function background(){
  document.getElementById("myBackground").style.visibility="visible";
   document.getElementById("favSubjects").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("hobbies").style.visibility="hidden";
  document.getElementById("contactMe").style.visibility="hidden";
}
```

The html:

```
      <button onclick="background()" class="buttons b1" id="Background">
        My Background
      </button>
```

```
      <p id="myBackground">
        I am from ...
      </p>
```

Comment: use `display:none`, like this : `document.getElementById("myBackground").style.display = "none";`. `Visibility:hidden` will hide the elements, but still occupy the space.

Comment: For reference, see [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility): "The visibility CSS property shows or hides an element *without changing the layout of a document*." Compare with [`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display): "Turns off the display of an element *so that it has no effect on layout* (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist)."

Comment: Is there a way I can undo ```display:none```? Because now the button can make the paragraphs disappear but the other buttons can't make them reappear

Answer (score 3):

You want something more like `display:none` which will actually hide the object (visibility:hidden and opacity:0 will make the object invisible, but still take up space).

Even still, you could make your life a little easier by using classes. Give all those elements the same class name and set a new class for hiding things. This example shows how you can access a group of elements that share a common class and toggle the hide/show.

```js
function background() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.hideable').forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hidden'));
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='this' class='hideable'>
  Hide me
</div>
<span id='that' class='hideable'>
Hide me
</span>
<ul>
  <li>Keep me</li>
  <li class='hideable'>Hide me</li>
</ul>

<button onclick='background()'>Toggle on/off elements</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting display:none to hide and set display:block to show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that simple way,

```js
    function background() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myBackground");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```html
<p id="myBackground"> I am from ... </p>
<button onclick="background()" class="buttons b1" id="Background"> My Background </button>
```